# using self signed certificate for my ssl site

Tags: ssl-certificate, ios8.1

I added the certificate to my device and to the simulator. If I go to the https site from Safari it works fine. If I try to do the same from my iPad Air it fails with error "the certificate is invalid.You might be connecting to a server that is pretending ..."
Why would it work from Safari but not from my app?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you already installed/trusted the self-signed certificate on your computer  then Safari (your desktop browser) won't prompt you, whereas on iOS you haven't opted to trust the certificate. Note that iOS 7+ does not let you see which certificates you have already trusted, you can only choose "Reset Settings" to remove all trust (silly, I know).

Comment: I emailed the certificate to myself then added it by using Safari on my iPad and iPhone. Now it is trusted on both but still gives the same error .

Comment: It looks like self signed certificate will not work on IOS devices. I changed to a certificate from a CA and everything works fine.